# How to test if a value is already in my HashMap while reading a file

Tags: java, if-statement, hashmap, set

I am working currently on a program to find similar sets. I need to map all my items contained in many sets in a HashMap with key, value pairs but I don't want redundant items to have many keys like key=1 value=bread and key=2 value=bread

So I wrote the following code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    // HashMap to stock all my items with keys that i will use for minhashing
    HashMap<Integer,String> hmap= new HashMap<>();
    List<List<Integer>> MinHash = new ArrayList<>();

    //to read my sets that i defined 
    FileReader in=new FileReader("C:\\items\\items.txt");
    BufferedReader brr = new BufferedReader(in);
    String item ; 
    int key=1; //for checking value pairs
    while( (item = brr.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(hmap.containsValue(item));
            if(hmap.containsValue(item)){//problem
                System.out.println("Item already in my map");
            else{
                hmap.put(key, item);
                key++;
            }
        }
    System.out.print(hmap);
}
```

But this test doesn't seem to return value true even if i have already this value in my HashMap

Comment: Only debugging can help, did you try trimming your items ?

Comment: This wouldn't be the cause of `containsValue` failing, but the `containsValue` method is extremely inefficient -- if you want efficient detection of duplicates, make the `String` the key, or use a `Set` instead of (or in addition to) a `Map`. The use of the `Integer` key is strange too. If you merely want an incrementing integer index, use a `List`.

Comment: Would you mind posting your items.txt file?

Comment: For what it's worth, it doesn't look like you need a `Map` here at all - you're not really associating *keys* with values, you're just sticking a bunch of values in a collection (and associating them with their index).  A `List<String>` would do that job just as well and wouldn't require you to manually increment the index.  Or if you don't need the index to be explicit, a `LinkedHashSet<String>` will automatically avoid duplicates while keeping the values in the order they were read from the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code worked as is, just need an extra bracket "}" after your second "System.out" line.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    // HashMap to stock all my items with keys that i will use for minhashing
    HashMap<Integer, String> hmap = new HashMap<>();
    List<List<Integer>> MinHash = new ArrayList<>();

    //to read my sets that i defined
    FileReader in = new FileReader("C:\\test\\items.txt");
    BufferedReader brr = new BufferedReader(in);
    String item;
    int key = 1; //for checking value pairs
    while ((item = brr.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(hmap.containsValue(item));
        if (hmap.containsValue(item)) {//problem
            System.out.println("Item already in my map");
        }
            else{
                hmap.put(key, item);
                key++;
            }
        }
        System.out.print(hmap);
    }
}
```

Outputs:
false
false
false
false
true
Item already in my map
{1=test, 2=blah, 3=asdf, 4=wefr}

Answer (score 0):

I tried to duplicate your issue with this code, and actually worked:

```
String[] list = ["hola1","hola2","hola3","hola4","hola2"];
int key = 1;
HashMap<Integer,String> hMap = new HashMap<Integer,String>()
for (String item : list) {
    if (hMap.containsValue(item)) {
        println("Found it: " + item);
    } else {
        hMap.put(key, item);
        key++;
    }
}
System.out.print(hMap);
```

The main difference is that a new item String is created for each value read it from the list.

Try something like this:

```
String itemToStore = item;
```

And then evaluate:

```
if(hmap.containsValue(itemToStore)) {
```

I'm guessing that storing the same item object might not work right; so explicitly, create a new object and store it.

I tested your code after doing so minor adjustments, and looks to be working for me:

```
HashMap<Integer,String> hmap= new HashMap<>();
List<List<Integer>> MinHash = new ArrayList<>();

//to read my sets that i defined 
FileReader fR = new FileReader("C:\\tmp\\items.txt");
BufferedReader brr = new BufferedReader(fR);
String item ; 
int key=1; //for checking value pairs
while( (item = brr.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(hmap.containsValue(item));
        if(hmap.containsValue(item)){//problem
            System.out.println("Item already in my map: " + item);
        }else{
            hmap.put(key, item);
            key++;
        }
    }
System.out.print(hmap);
```

This is in the file:
hola1
hola2
hola3
hola4
hola2

This is the output:
Item already in my map: hola2
[1:hola1, 2:hola2, 3:hola3, 4:hola4]

Sfc

Comment: You may want to read from file instead of using static string. They are different.

Comment: Using a static string was only to prove the basic concept. This is not a code to copy paste. About gibberish... well...

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and ran a test. It actually worked. But there was a small syntax error

```
System.out.println(hmap.containsValue(item));
if(hmap.containsValue(item))//{//problem  <-- an extra "{"
    System.out.println("Item already in my map");
else{
    hmap.put(key, item);
    key++;
}
```

So you want to provide more details such as the text file?

Comment: I noticed OP was edited by @stivan, he added this "{". Any reason for that?

Answer (score -1):

Your keyvalue is an Integer, but you are looking with your variable "item", which is a String. You can only look for existing keys!

Comment: Sorry but, that's just not true. You CAN look for existing values. Why else have a [```containsKey```](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#containsKey-java.lang.Object-) and a [```containsValue```](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#containsValue-java.lang.Object-) method.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use

```
BufferedReader brr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\items\\items.txt"));
```

instead of

```
FileReader in=new FileReader("C:\\items\\items.txt");
```

Comment: Why in the world would putting two lines on one line make any difference?

Comment: You're right, I had a bad day and mis-read... I'm sorry for my mistake!